# $(window).on("focus", ...) not working on chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

There´s a question asking for the same, but it doesn't have a satisfactory answer as I already tried it.

This is my code:

```
$(window).on("focus", function() {
    doSomeFunction();
    alert("I am here!");
});
```

I'm using window because document wasn't working even on chrome desktop, someone suggested using window here in stackoverflow and it works on desktop at least, but in chrome mobile is another case.

With firefox mobile I can switch tabs, press home and reopen firefox, press home, swipe close and reopen firefox and I get the alert message, with chrome none of those cases work.

Need to find a way to make it work on that browser, remember, it works on chrome and firefox desktop and firefox mobile but not on chrome mobile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) would be a good option?

Comment: @StevenV got a solution myself, I'm gonna self answer for anybody else having this issue, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution, it's probably not the best but it works.

Aparently chrome mobile is not catching this event when is placed on .js files
so I just have to place it on a  tag in my html document:

```
<script>
    $(window).on("focus", function() {
        doSomeFunction();
        alert("I am here!");
    });
</script>
```

In this case, it doesn't matter if doSomeFunction() is in the DOM or in a .js file, just make sure the focus event is in the DOM